# Branch Policy in Github

Tags: github

I have 2 branches in my github repository. How do I enforce a branch policy for Master branch such that any changes to it must require a code review from specific folks done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best managed by repos, not branches.

You can have one repo with the `master` branch, and one or several **[forks](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/)**, from which developers can make [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/) in order to request a merge to `master` of the original repo.

Only the "specific folks" are declared collaborators on the original repo, and can review the PRs and merge them.

Then the [developers can synchronize their own fork](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/).